# Deleted function and ADL

Tags: c++, overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I came across the following confusing example involving ADL and deleted functions:

First Example:

```
namespace A
{
    struct S{};

    void f(S){cout << "adl" << endl;}
}

namespace C
{
    //void f() = delete;

    //void f (double);

    void test()
    {
        A::S arg;
        f(arg);
    }
}


int main()
{
    C::test();

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, `A::f` is called through ADL. In the next example, there is a deleted function with the same name in `C`:

```
namespace A
{
    struct S{};

    void f(S){cout << "adl" << endl;}
}

namespace C
{
    void f() = delete;

    //void f (double);

    void testi()
    {
        A::S arg;
        f(arg);
    }
}


int main()
{
    C::testi();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling fails with the error message `error: use of deleted function 'void C::f()'`. Apparently, the deleted functions stops the ADL version from getting into the overloading table. Now for the last example: In addition to the deleted function there is now another, not-deleted, function with the same name:

```
namespace A
{
    struct S{};

    void f(S){cout << "adl" << endl;}
}

namespace C
{
    void f() = delete;

    void f (double);

    void testi()
    {
        A::S arg;
        f(arg);
    }
}


int main()
{
    C::testi();

    return 0;
}
```

Running this executes the ADL version of `f`. So in conclusion:

- Having no matching function the current namespace results in the ADL version being called
- Having just the deleted function in the current namespace results in an error, probably because the ADL version is not discovered at all
- Having another, non-deleted, function in the current namespace results in the ADL version being called.

My questions: Is this behaviour intentional? If so, which part of the standard specifies this?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I used onlinegdb for compilation, so gcc/g++ was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definite compiler bug. To quote the C++ standard draft (n4659) [[dcl.fct.def.delete]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.delete#2):

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly,
>   other than to declare it, is ill-formed. [ Note: This includes calling
>   the function implicitly or explicitly and forming a pointer or
>   pointer-to-member to the function. It applies even for references in
>   expressions that are not potentially-evaluated. **If a function is
>   overloaded, it is referenced only if the function is selected by
>   overload resolution**. The implicit odr-use of a virtual function does
>   not, by itself, constitute a reference.  — end note ]

Overload resolution cannot select that overload by ADL. So this function shouldn't be referenced. The second code sample is a well-formed C++ program (if the missing include directives are put back in).

---

You mentioned using g++ to compile, note that this issue is [fixed in GCC 7.2.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac2337642802bd2f)

Comment: I just realized that g++ 5.4.1 c++14 was used in my example

Comment: @LcdDrm - You can use [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) and do a binary search by GCC version to learn exactly when it was fixed, if you wish :)

Comment: GCC 6.3 fails, GCC 7.1 works. The MS Visual Studio compiler works too